# How to make jquery bind event work

Tags: jquery, events, bind

For some reason my bind events won't work.
You can see my code here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/145581/MyPage/default.html

Clicking on 'Add gadget' or the 'Remove gadget' button should be firing alerts but nothing happens.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you move your `bind()` methods inside the `$(document).ready()` event. Since they are being called before the DOM is ready (namely before those DOM elements even exist) there is no way for an event to be bound to them.

Also, passing in objects to `bind()` isn't supported until jQuery 1.4. (You can use the code I have below, or upgrade to 1.4 to use your `bind()` methods as is. (you'll still need to move them to inside the `ready()` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // enable sortable on all columns
    // this will add drag-and-drop functionality as well
    $("#mypage_column1").sortable({
        items: '.gadget', // the type of element to drag
        handle: 'h2', // the element that should start the drag event
        opacity: 0.9, // opacity of the element while draging
        connectWith: ["#mypage_column2"]
    });

    $("#mypage_column2").sortable({
        items: '.gadget', // the type of element to drag
        handle: 'h2', // the element that should start the drag event
        opacity: 0.9, // opacity of the element while draging
        connectWith: ["#mypage_column1"]
    });

    $("img.btn_delete").bind('click', function() {
        alert("Removing this gadget");
      });

    $("img.mypage_add_gadget").bind('click', function() {
        alert("Adding a new gadget");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your calls to `bind` are made outside of your `$(document).ready( )` handler, so your elements aren't there yet. Either move them into `$(document).ready()` or use jQuery's `live(...)`.